# Morphisms into polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $k[x]$ be the polynomial ring. Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and further assume that it is not a field. Let $m$ a maximal ideal of $R$ such that $R/m \simeq k$.

Then does there always exist a ring morphism $\phi : R \rightarrow k[x]$ such that ideal $(x)$ in $k[x]$ contracts to $m$ , that is, $\phi^{-1}(x)=m$. If that is true, then is it also true that given two maximal ideals $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ (such that $R/m_{i} \simeq k $ for $i=1,2$ ), there exists a morphism $\phi : R \rightarrow k[x]$ such that ideal $(x)$ contracts to $m_{1}$ and $(x-1)$ contracts to $m_{2}$.

Comment: What does "contracts to mean" in this context? And what have you tried?

Comment: Contract means inverse image . I can prove both the statements when $R$ is a finite type algebra over k.

Comment: Well i suppose Atiyah Macdonald uses the same terminology. I was about to make the edit that R is not of the form $K[x]/I$

Comment: I am not sure you have a correct proof for affine algebras, since it is false even for those in general. For example, (assume for simplicity $k=\mathbb{C}$) try $R=k[u,v]/u^2-v^3-v$ and $m=(u,v)$. The  only way you can do this is by the trivial map $R\to k\subset k[x]$, not very interesting. In particular, the answer to the second is no.

Comment: @ironfeliks: if it's the terminology in Atiyah and MacDonald, that's good enough for me. Sorry about my digression.

Comment: @mohan thanks for pointing it out, i made a stupid error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, yes: just let $R$ be the composition of the quotient map $R\to R/m\cong k$ with the inclusion of the constants $k\to k[x]$.

In the second case, no.  For instance, let $k=\mathbb{Q}$, $R=\mathbb{Q}[x,x^{-1}]$, $m_1=(x-1)$ and $m_2=(x-2)$. Note that the image of any homomorphism $\phi:R\to\mathbb{Q}[x]$ consists entirely of constants, since $x$ must map to a unit and the only units in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ are constants.  So for any such $\phi$, $\phi^{-1}(x)=\phi^{-1}(x-1)=\ker(\phi)$.

Geometrically, if $R$ is a $k$-algebra and you ask for $\phi$ to be a homomorphism of $k$-algebras, you are asking whether any two $k$-points of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ can be connected by a morphism from $\mathbb{A}^1$.  This is usually false.

Comment: Actually that was the motivation behind question whether two $k$ valued points on a scheme are connected by an $\mathbb A^{1}$ morphism